# How to change a TextView automatically when an EditText & Seekbar is changed

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My application works like this:
It has 4 `EditText` (input type: number) which are programmatically linked to 4 `Seekbar`. If `EditText` A is changed, then `Seekbar` A's progress will change according to the `EditText` A's number value. If `EditText` A's value is 40, then the `Seekbar` will change its progress to 40%. Vice-versa, if I drag `Seekbar` A's progress to 50%, then the `EditText` value will be 50.

And then I have this `TextView`, which I want to show the total value of A & B & C & D. So, if A is changed (either with `Seekbar` / `EditText`), the value will also change.

I've tried to

```
setText((Integer.parseInt(EditTextA.getText().toString())) + (Integer.parseInt(EditTextB.getText().toString()) + (Integer.parseInt(EditTextC.getText().toString()) + (Integer.parseInt(EditTextD.getText().toString()));
```

but it gives me error:

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String
>   resource ID #0x0

And even if it works, it also doesn't solve what I have to do with the seekbars.

---

My code for the seekbar & editText:

```
        seekbarPrice.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            valuePrice.setText(String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()));

        }
    });

    valuePrice.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            try {
                seekbarPrice.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(editable.toString()));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
            ;
        }
    });
```

---

### Thanks in advance!

edit:
@Muthukrishnan Rajendran 's solution worked, but it gives me another error.

If I change edittext A without erasing all the numbers in the edittext first (like 40 -> 4 (erase 5)-> 45), the code works.
But if i erase all of the numbers first (40 -> (erase all)) it gives me this error:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: id.ac.umn.mobile.skripsi, PID: 5996
                                                                    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                                        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                                                                        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                                                                        at PreferencesActivity.updateText(PreferencesActivity.java:53)
                                                                        at PreferencesActivity.access$000(PreferencesActivity.java:40)
                                                                        at PreferencesActivity$2.afterTextChanged(PreferencesActivity.java:118)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7689)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:9482)
                                                                        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:972)
                                                                        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:516)
                                                                        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:216)
                                                                        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:33)
                                                                        at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(BaseInputConnection.java:244)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:389)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5247)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
```

line 118 is:
@Override

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            try {
                seekbarPrice.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(editable.toString()));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
            updateText();
        }
    });
```

updateText() is line 118. that is a part of the edittext that I erase the value

Answer (score 1):

If you try to set `int` value, I will try to search the resource, so try to convert it into String and set in TextView it will work.

Two methods are there [`TextView.setText(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)) and `TextView.setText(CharSequence text)`, First one will point to the resource id, You gave `int` so it's trying to search resource for that int value.

Set like this,

```
setText(String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(EditTextA.getText().toString())) + (Integer.parseInt(EditTextB.getText().toString()) + (Integer.parseInt(EditTextC.getText().toString()) + (Integer.parseInt(EditTextD.getText().toString())));
```

For Each SeekBar create on boolean like below and follow the steps,

```
private boolean isChangeByProgressBarA = false;

private void updateText() {
   setText(String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(EditTextA.getText().toString())) + (Integer.parseInt(EditTextB.getText().toString()) + (Integer.parseInt(EditTextC.getText().toString()) + (Integer.parseInt(EditTextD.getText().toString())));
}

seekbarPrice.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                if(isChangeByProgressBarA) {
                    valuePrice.setText(String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()));
                }

                updateText();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                isChangeByProgressBarA = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                isChangeByProgressBarA = false;
             }
        });

        valuePrice.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                try {
                       if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editable.toString())) {

       seekbarPrice.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(editable.toString()));
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

                updateText();
            }
        });
```

Do this for all text or you can put single listener and check based on Id.

Comment: I tried that, while it fixed the error, the number of the TextView is 0, and it didnt change at all when I change the EditText & SeekBar...

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and report back asap!

Comment: Sure, Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! I didnt use the boolean stuff & didnt change anything on the seekbar code because I figure out the edittext code itself already changes the seekbar & vice versa, so if the seekbar is changed, it will change the edittext and calls the updatetext function

Comment: Try to verify your code once more, you may get round robin method.

Comment: Another error: if I select all the numbers and change it (like 40 -> 50), it works fine, but if I erase the all of the numbers first, then change it, it gives me this error: afterTextChanged(PreferencesActivity.java:118) -> which is the updateText() function on the erased edittext.aftertextchanged

Comment: Add your complete log trace.

Comment: Just did it, sorry I forgot

Comment: Yous text is empty, so do like this **if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editable.toString())) {

       seekbarPrice.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(editable.toString()));
                    }** , I updated my answer too